# Move all values of array into one variable in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, variables, arraylist

I have a very simple question.

Imagine I have this array :

```
$array = array("one","two","three");
```

I want to merge all values into one variable :

```
$array = "one,two,three";
```

How to do it ?

Comment: `implode(",",$array);` simple!!

Comment: Why did you asked a simple question here, as you know the answer??

Comment: @ShaunakShukla Thanks, i have forgot this function !

Comment: @ShaunakShukla i Known answer by your comment :) Tnx

Comment: oh.. most wlcome.. you can find it from php.net or google as well..

Comment: Also, you can use the alias function [join](http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php)

Answer (score 1):

By using this :

```
$variable = implode(",",$array);
```